# MySQL official documentation unclear

Tags: mysql

Could someone explain to me the last part of this [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions-frames.html) of Window Function Frame Specification. Precisely the part of frame specification when the current row value is NULL:

> The meaning of a frame specification can be nonobvious when the
> current row value is NULL. Assuming that to be the case, these
> examples illustrate how various frame specifications apply:
>
> ```
> ORDER BY X ASC RANGE BETWEEN 10 FOLLOWING AND 15 FOLLOWING
> ```
>
> The frame starts at
> NULL and stops at NULL, thus includes only rows with value NULL.
>
> ```
> ORDER BY X ASC RANGE BETWEEN 10 FOLLOWING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING
> ```
>
> The
> frame starts at NULL and stops at the end of the partition. Because an
> ASC sort puts NULL values first, the frame is the entire partition.
>
> ...

I did my research but found nothing explaining this part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you specify the frame using a specific number of rows preceding or following the current row, and the column value in the current row is `NULL`, the row count is limited to the adjacent rows with `NULL` values. For instance, if you specify `10 PRECEDING` and there are 5 preceding rows with null values, and 5 non-null rows before them, it will only include the 5 null rows in the frame.

But if you specify `UNBOUNDED`, it will go to the end of the partition in that direction, not just use the rows with null values.